# Scalability problems pivot table Pandas/Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, scalability, collaborative-filtering

I am trying to build a collaborative filtering recommender system where I compare users and items in a sparse data-matrix.

The data:

```py
5.149.754 unique ids
7.827.435 unique items
```

Data is implicit, so items are liked by users if they have clicked on them. Data is thus either a `1` or `0` per item.

I am having issues with the scalability. I am trying to use `Pandas`, `NumPy` and `SciPy` to build a sparse user-item matrix, but I am getting  errors (obviously?):

`Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow` w/ Pandas pivot

`MemoryError` w/ Numpy pivot_table

Even with a `Pandas DataFrame` of 642736 rows with profileIds and itemIds I am getting these errors. It is possible to split up the data in categories by variables such as `age` and `gender`.

Ultimately I am trying to recommend items to users based on as many users/items as possible, but I do not understand the limits of such a system as I do not have the experience of working with such a large dataset.

How would you implement such a system? Is it necessary to split up data? is there some library/documentation I should read before going ahead with this?

Comment: Sounds like the table is just too big, which makes me think "use dask", which should provide most of the functionality of numpy/pandas but handles it out-of-memory. A question about your data: is it a table where each column is an item and each row is an id, with the cells being `0`or `1`? Splitting up might be a viable solution, but if you want to analyze it all, I recommend looking at dask: https://dask.org/

Comment: could you show what you're doing to get that error?  i.e. are you really trying to create a 5M by 8M = 4e13 entry matrix?  even if this is sparse, it's going to take **a lot** of memory!  you're going to have to think of other ways of working with/representing this data

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that's my question exactly: how to work with this data. Yes, the table is an item in each column and each row is an id, cells being ```0``` or ```1```. Will look into dask